# Error with pip install: 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I'm not familiar with Python, just trying to implement some software so please ELI5 if you can.

I was instructed to download Python, PyWin32, and Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7. I attached the links to the versions, these are downlaod links.

https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.14/python-2.7.14.amd64.msi https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20221/pywin32-221.win-amd64-py2.7.exe/download
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=44266

When I go to cmd prompt to enter
pip install pyOpenSSL

I get the error
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

python 2.7 doesn't come with pip. you have to install it first.
take a look at-
[How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows)

Comment: so I believe the python version is 2.7.14 right? It should already come with it but when I tried to execute the py -3 -m ensurepip
it said "py is not recognized as an internal or external command" as well

Comment: can you access the python interpreter on command line? and also check for pip --version

Comment: sorry how do I do both of those things? not familiar with this

Comment: open command prompt and type python
check if you get '>>>' interactive prompt with python version details. exit interpreter using ctrl+z.
and did you set python path during installation of python?

Comment: it says python is not recognized as a command if I type that in but if I enter in C:\python27\python.exe I get details with an interactive prompt, version is 2.7.14.

Not sure I just hit download and kept hitting next until it completed.

Comment: ok. so you have to set that path in path environment variable.
try this and set the variable and check again if you can access the interpreter by typing python only. add C:\python27


https://geek-university.com/python/add-python-to-the-windows-path/